# Using SageMaker with Hydra

Tags: python, yaml, amazon-sagemaker, fb-hydra, omegaconf

I have a question about SageMaker and Hydra.

**TL;DR**
Is there a way to pass arguments from SageMaker estimator to a Hydra script? Currently it passes parameters in a very strict way.

**Full Question**
I use Hydra in order to pass configs to my training script. I have many configs and it works good for my. For example, if I want to use a specific optimizer, I do:

```
python train.py optimizer=adam
```

This is my training script, for instance:

```
@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path="configs/", config_name="config")
def train(config: DictConfig):
    logging.info(f"Instantiating dataset <{config.dataset._target_}>")
    train_ds, val_ds = hydra.utils.call(config.dataset)

    logging.info(f"Instantiating model <{config.model._target_}>")
    model = hydra.utils.call(config.model)

    logging.info(f"Instantiating optimizer <{config.optimizer._target_}>")
    optimizer = hydra.utils.instantiate(config.optimizer)

    logging.info(f"Instantiating loss <{config.loss._target_}>")
    loss = hydra.utils.instantiate(config.loss)

    callbacks = []
    if "callbacks" in config:
        for _, cb_conf in config.callbacks.items():
            if "_target_" in cb_conf:
                logging.info(f"Instantiating callback <{cb_conf._target_}>")
                callbacks.append(hydra.utils.instantiate(cb_conf))

    metrics = []
    if "metrics" in config:
        for _, metric_conf in config.metrics.items():
            if "_target_" in metric_conf:
                logging.info(f"Instantiating metric <{metric_conf._target_}>")
                metrics.append(hydra.utils.instantiate(metric_conf))

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)

    model.fit(
        train_ds,
        validation_data=val_ds,
        epochs=config.epochs,
        callbacks=callbacks,
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    train()
```

And I have a relevant `optimizer/adam.yaml` file.

Now, I started using SageMaker to run my experiments in the cloud and I noticed a problem.
It doesn't support the hydra syntax (`+optimizer=sgd`), stuff like that.

Is there a way to make it play nicely with Hydra syntax? If not, do you have a suggestion for refactoring my training code so that it would work nicely with Hydra/OmegaConf?

I saw there is a similar question in SageMaker issues page, but it doesn't have any replies:
https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/1837

Comment: Do you find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at passing the arguments as ENVs and ingesting them in your training script?

You can pass a dict containing the ENVs:
https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html#estimators

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Hydra's [Compose API](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.2/advanced/compose_api/). This way you can preprocess the command-line args passed to your python program before they are ingested by Hydra.